# Grub memory map not going beyond 3.5GB

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I am trying to learn OS development by building a small kernel. I'm using physical memory map provided by GRUB. The problem is upto 3.5 GB memory, the results are fine but beyond that, the highest accessible memory is shown as 3gb no matter what the physical memory size is. The kernel is higher half and located at 3gb(virtual) and it is run on a single core CPU. Can someone point out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classical "3.5GB issue" is a memory-mapped video card.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @rithvikp: There are 4 billion addresses available using 32 bits. As the GDDR on a memory-mapped videocard needs some of those addresses (512 MB is a common amount), only 3.5 GB addresses remain for ordinary RAM.

Comment: Oh, I never knew that. Thanks a lot!